# How can I level out my auto scaling checks?

Tags: amazon-ec2, autoscaling, amazon-cloudwatch

So, I have been playing around with my auto scaling config and my Cloudwatch alarms to try and keep all my instances purring but not roaring.

I can't seem to get rid of a constant yoyo. CPU usage goes up, introduce an instance, CPU usage goes down, kill an instance. Rinse and repeat.

[image]

I'm currently basing my alarm on 3 x 1min intervals of average CPU >= 40%. Maybe I can base it on something else? CPU is a tricky one as when this graph is spiking (high) I can see some instances with idle CPU so the average is being raised by a single instance.

I'm finding some people are getting 502's when I'm getting 200's. Obviously I would like this to be consistent and stop this spiking all the times.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:** I have adjusted the Cloudwatch metric to be 20% cpu over 2 mins and also found an nginx error that *may* also have attributed to some additional load. Current graph looks like the below.

[image]

**EDIT 2:** Monitoring on load is *so* much better. See below for the load alarm. I'm getting alerts far less frequently and everything is running much nicer.

This is what I'm running in cron every minute;

```
/usr/local/bin/aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --namespace="NS" --metric-name="GroupLoad" --value `cat /proc/loadavg | awk '{print $1}'` --dimensions AutoScalingWebGroup=NS-WebGroup
```

[image]

Comment: Try load instead if CPU?

Comment: Um .. You can't configure scaling on load. Or, if you can (thatd be awesome) I havent found it. :(

Comment: Should be straight forward, have a look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/as-scale-based-on-demand.html and http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-user-defined-metrics/

Comment: Nice. I'll have a read.

Comment: I've started adding load metrics to Cloudwatch. This is the script I wrote; https://gist.github.com/cbiggins/fa656876ecaa7d210c19. If you add your comment as the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: nps, done. hopefully load will work much better than cpu for scaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of AutoScaling based on **CPU** try **Server Load**.

AWS AutoScaling can operate on any CloudWatch metric, and you can write your own custom CloudWatch metrics.

More Information on how AutoScaling works: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/as-scale-based-on-demand.html

## Creating a custom metric

http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-user-defined-metrics/

> CloudWatch metrics are scoped within namespaces, and can be further
>   qualified by up to 10 dimensions. For example, latency could be
>   tracked for a pair of applications ("App1" and "App2") while keeping
>   the values isolated from each other:

```
$ mon-put-data -namespace App1 -metric-name Latency -value 104
$ mon-put-data -namespace App2 -metric-name Latency -value 120
```

Comment: Thanks. Just need to work out how to group the values to do an average now.

Comment: I just updated the question with info on the load monitoring if you're interested. Works perfectly.

Comment: nice, looks much better :)